# CSS inheritance transitions

Tags: css, inheritance, css-transitions

I have this HTML: `<nav><a href="#">text</a> in red</nav>` 
http://jsfiddle.net/208ycs56/

why do I need to add

```
-moz-transition: all 3s ease;
-o-transition: all 3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
transition: all 3s ease;
```

twice in order it to work nicely? Move it from nav to `a` and `a:hover`
so why does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/208ycs56/1/) work and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/208ycs56/) does not...

Please check my working and non-working sample and let me know why one works and the other does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not inherited…

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp

> **Note:** Always specify the transition-duration property, otherwise the duration is 0, and the transition will have no effect.
>
> **Default value:**    all 0 ease 0
>
> ***Inherited: no***
>
> **Animatable:**   no. Read about animatable
>
> **Version:**  CSS3

Comment: Right, and use of the transition only at the element itself. No declaration on the hover state necessary. See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/208ycs56/8/

Comment: Thank you for the nice addition. The pseudo class does inherit

Comment: It's worth noting that if you desire different transition behaviors (e.g. duration, timing function) when hovering on vs. hovering off, that is a good reason to add a `transition` property to `:hover` as well.